# "На глубину" или "в глубину"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: Опускаться *на* глубину или опускаться *в* глубину?

Comment: Я прошу, не изменяйте названия. Громоздкие, они выглядят некрасиво. Все равно текст вопроса виден. Давайте уже кто-то один будет модерить форум, ага? Есть уже устоявшиеся теги и форма заголовков.  
Спасибо за понимание. Администратор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в общем-то и так и так можно.
Есть, видимо, некая смысловая разница, "на глубину" - положение, окончательная цель, "в глубину" - процесс, движения в данном напралении. Но эта разница не очень выражена в разговорной речи. 
У моряков обычно "на глубину". "В глубину" - это разве что на грунт при окончательном затоплении.
Но интересно, что обратное движение - "из глубины". Так что предлоги даже в профессиональной речи путаются.

Answer (score 2):

На глубину 400 метров (опуститься). В глубину (в глубь) моря.